# Acceder a varios registros del portapapeles en Windows desde powershell

Tags: powershell

Con Windows 10 es posible almacenar varias copias en el portapapeles, luego pulsas Windows+V y las pegas donde quieras. He tratado de acceder a través de Power Shell al portapapeles y poder extraer varias entradas, pero siempre me devuelve la última con el comando Get-Clipboard y no encuentro forma de que me devuelva, por ejemplo, un array de elementos. ¿Alguien sabe si es posible acceder a varias entradas del Clipboard a través de Power Shell? He consultado la web, incluso en inglés, pero no di con nada. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7.3), sólo vas a acceder al contenido actual, como texto, y no es posible entregarle parámetros a ese cmdlet. Es más, si copias un directorio o algo que no sea un texto, ese cmdlet va a retornar nulo. Así que por ahí no es.

[Este amigo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230303-00/?p=107894) indica que es posible usando `GetHistoryItemsAsync` y un `await` para enumerar los elementos dentro del resultado:

```
$null = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard, Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer, ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
$op = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard]::GetHistoryItemsAsync()

$result = Await ($op) `
    ([Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ClipboardHistoryItemsResult])

$textops = $result.Items.Content.GetTextAsync()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $textops.Count; $i++){ Await($textops[$i]) ([String]) }
```

Comment: Genial alfabravo, muchísimas gracias.